# Windows phone 7 Advertisement

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, ads

I am developing an application in which I need to display the ads. So now the problem is I cannot use ad-control that is provided by Microsoft. The client has said that he will provide different types of ads like banner,interstitial,gallery and expandable ads. Are there any policies that prohibit me to use my own controls to display the ads rather than using ad-control by Microsoft?

Comment: Huh? Whats the question?

Comment: Whether I can write my own control to display the ads that are provided by my client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is legal, but there are policies regarding WP7 advertising:

Here’s official text from the Microsoft Windows Phone 7 Marketplace guidelines:

> 2.7 If your application includes or displays advertising, the advertising must comply with     the [Microsoft Advertising Creative Acceptance Policy Guide](http://advertising.microsoft.com/creative-specs).

Comment: That doesn't prevent using another ad network/code than MS's.

Comment: sorry, i ment yes this is acceptable not yes there are policies against this.